# How to put scorm packages externally into moodle?

Tags: php, file-upload, moodle, scorm, moodle-api

I have a specific requirement. 
How one can put scorm packages externally but using moodle scorm uploading functionality so that the package content will show up in moodle course.

It is like, i am putting all scorm activity details in DB from back end and wants to put the package also from back end without using any UI thing to upload the content.

I can simply move the file but moodle used to encrypt it before storing. so i have to use moodle scorm uploading functionality from backend.

If anyone have any idea or any other way to solve this, Please let me know.

Comment: Please correct me if I get it wrong. You want to bypass the _upload a file_ page of Moodle but not Moodle system at all, init?

Comment: @coner , sorry for the late response.. yes, exactly.  I don't want to use moodle ui part to upload the scorm. I need to write some sort of cron job to automate this process, but do not know how??!!

Answer (score 2):

You can enable this feature in site administration. It's called "Enable external package type". [Here's instructions](https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/SCORM_settings).

Comment: So can i update that url in scorm table from back end? is that will work? if so, but i am not able to see any field for external url in mdl_scorm?       Is that we have to store in some other field. The main concern is, i cannot use UI. I have to write some cron job or some db script through which my scorm activity should be ready to explore.